# LightningChartJS - Is it possible to enable cursor with ChartXY & AxisScrollStrategy (progressive)

Tags: lightningchart

I'm using **LightningChartJS** v. 3.0.1 and have a chart with scroll strategy.

Live example: https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/examples/lcjs-example-0803-scrollingHeatmap.html

Is it possible to enable the cursor on user hover while the series is scrolling ?

The current behavior showing the cursor only when the series stops scrolling (you can double tap one of the axis to check it out)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior of disabling cursor while series is scrolling can be modified with the method [`ChartXY.setMouseInteractionsWhileScrolling`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v3.0.1/classes/chartxy.html#setmouseinteractionswhilescrolling)

However, I looked into it and it turns out that there is a bug and this method is not working properly in latest version or v.3.0.1.

Here's a snippet that seems to achieve what you want in v.3.0.1

```
chartXY.setMouseInteractionsWhileZooming(true)
```

After next version v.3.4.0 we will have fixed the bug after which you should use the intended method `setMouseInteractionsWhileScrolling`, not "zooming".

EDIT: The fix will be postponed to version v.4.0.0 because it is a breaking change which could have a detrimental effect on existing user applications when they do a minor version update.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your fast feedback. I'll be looking forward to v3.4.0  :)